# HP 6570b video driver

Tags: brightness, hp, gpu-driver

I am sorry if this is a duplicate question, but after 2 days I did not find the answer to this problem, and I would really appreciate a link to a solution.
I have been trying to get a video driver on my laptop so that brightness up and down shortcuts (FN+F9 / FN+F10) work.

In additional drivers only the *xserver-xorg-video-ati*  drivers are working fine for me (but without brightness control: adjusting the value in /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness, but the actual screen brightness stays max). With the proprietary drivers (fglrx and fglrx-updates) ubuntu loads to the logon screen, but after logon just the desktop image is displayed.

I tried to write in /etc/default/grub:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

... but that removed the adjusting brightness option from the system settings and the shortcuts did not do anything.

Hp has a video driver for linux for the 6570b notebook series , [link](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=321957&prodSeriesId=5212927&prodNameId=5212928&swEnvOID=2020&swLang=13&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=ob-105065-1).

It is tar.gz file with two .rpm packages:

- ati-fglrxG02-HP-kmp-default-8.954_3.0.13_0.27-1.1.x86_64.rpm
- x11-video-fglrxG02-HP-8.954-1.1.x86_64.rpm

...using:

```
 sudo yum localinstall <one-of-the-two-above-packages>
```

I get a lot of unresolved dependencies and do not know how to fix that. Do I need to add additional software sources? I did not find any on the page where the driver can be downloaded.
How do I install the above provided linux dirivers by HP in ubuntu 12.10?

Answer (score 0):

With backlight try this

```
ls /sys/class/backlight
```

You can override which backlight is used with a snippet:

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier "Device0"
  Option "Backlight" "name_of_backlight"
EndSection
```

in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/backlight.conf`

Propably using `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight` should work.